# Launching PointOfSale from LoadRunerVugen-change in user.hooks loads the application but no recording and vice versa when recording not launching

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner, pos, vugen

**The application is java based and it launches the application with help of xml file in accordance it calls all jar files using batch file. I am using LoadRunner vugen protocol Java record replay  and triggers the application
but when its launching its not recording and vice versa when recording not launching - this happens when I change in user.hook file if you can help me to understand about this user.hook file (classes folder) that would be great**

```
Please find the format of user.hooks used below

; User Hooks definition file
; This file can be modified in order to place user specific hooks

;--------------------------- Hooks Section --------------------

; This is a sample hook -

[Hook-Name]
;---------- ClassName-MethodName --------

class      = MyPackage.MyClass
method     = MyMethod
signature  = ()V
cb_class   = mercury.ProtocolSupport
general_cb = true

;[Instance]
;---------- Stub hooks --------
;class      = !XXXXXXXXX.system.engine..*
;method     = !.*
;signature  = !.*
;cb_class   = mercury.rmi.RMISupport
;general_cb = true


[PosThread]
;---------- Stub hooks --------
class      = !XXXXXXXXX.system.engine.PosThread..*
method     = XXXXXXX
signature  = !.*
cb_class   = mercury.rmi.RMISupport
general_cb = true

;[GeneralResponse]
;---------- Stub hooks --------
;class      = !XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.db..*
;method     = !.*
;signature  = !.*
;cb_class   = mercury.rmi.RMISupport
;general_cb = true

[ClientHTTPServer]
;---------- Stub hooks --------
class      = XXXXXXXX.system.common.ClientHTTPServer
method     = !.*
signature  = !.*
ignore_mtd = !fetchEqual
cb_class   = mercury.rmi.RMISupport
general_cb = true

;[GeneralRequestor]
;---------- Stub hooks --------
;class      = XXXXXXX.system.common.GeneralRequestor
;method     = connectToServer
;signature  = !.*
;cb_class   = mercury.rmi.RMISupport
;general_cb = true

;[GeneralRequestor_pr]
;---------- Stub hooks --------
;class      = XXXXXXX.system.common.GeneralRequestor
;method     = process`enter code here`
;signature  = !.*
;cb_class   = mercury.rmi.RMISupport
;general_cb = true
```

Comment: Just record Winsock and see if something shows up

Comment: Tried Winsock protocol, Record as Windows application , Application as .bat file  and accordingly working directory but start recording option is still freezed

Comment: What version of LoadRunner.   What version of Windows (home, pro, enterprise, gates special edition, 64 bit, 32 bit, etc...   What version of Java?  32 bit? 64 bit?

Comment: @chandansharma you asked this on the forum and we are checking it out.

Comment: vugen 32 bit, java 8 64 bit, windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Normalize to all 32 bit on recording.  Make sure your version of Java is supported.   You should be able to record Winsock for anything.  That you cannot points to a failed install or an unsupported environment/version model